# What leads to the floating point exception "1.#IO"

Tags: windows-7, floating-point, fortran, invalidoperationexception, floating-point-exceptions

I'm debugging a simulation with many calculations in many Fortran files.  I am used to seeing some floating point exceptions (-1.#QNB or 1.#QNAN) for errors that involve division by zero or operations that exceed the maximum size for floating point number.  I'm assuming -1.#IO means invalid operation, but I'm not sure mathematically what would cause this and not QNB or QNAN or QINF.

What would lead to the exception -1.#IO?

Comment: CVF 6 is the compiler. The simulation is thousands of lines per second and I'm not sure where the exception first appears but it propogates -1.#IO to all of the other subroutines so eventually I have thousands of variables with this exception before it blows up.

Comment: Just division by zero: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130228-01/?p=5103

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [IEEE 754 Standard for Floating Point Operations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/IEEESTD.2008.4610935), the invalid operation is signaled

> when a NaN or infinite operand cannot be represented in the destination format and this cannot otherwise
>   be indicated [...] When a numeric operand would convert to
>   an integer outside the range of the destination format, the invalid operation exception shall  be signaled if
>   this situation cannot otherwise be indicated.

[This page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_handle.html) gives a few examples:

- zero * infinity
- zero / zero
- infinity / infinity
- square root of a negative operand
- [and a few more]